# How can you unstash changes using EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit, git-stash

When I switch branch with non-committed changes I'm given a prompt to stash my changes:

[image]

When I switch back to the branch with the stashed changes I can't see any of the non-committed changes.

Using EGit how can I retrieve the stashed changes?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

#### EGit 3.5 and later

In [EGit 3.5 and later](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/), there is a menu called *Stashes* in the *Team* context menu. It provides an action to stash changes and also lists any existing stashes. The same menu is also available as a toolbar icon and in the *Git Repositories* view:

[image: stash menu]

Selecting an existing stash from the menu opens it in a viewer. The changes can be inspected and there are actions for applying the stash or deleting it:

[image: stash viewer]

#### EGit 3.4 and ealier

1. Open the *Git Repositories* view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and typing, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> on Mac OS X)
2. Expand the node of the corresponding repository
3. Expand the *Stashed Commits* node
4. Open the context menu of the stash and select *Apply Stashed Changes*

Answer (score 3):

In Eclipse (Luna) + eGIT, you can restore stash as [image]

Comment: I see in this screenshot the item to stash changes, but NOT to pop (i.e., apply) stashed changes.  I see the same in Eclipse Mars + EGit.  What view, what item, what context menu (or whatever) allows applying (i.e., popping) a stashed change set?

Comment: To apply the stashed changes, goto Git Repository View and expand relevant repository node, there you would see the node "Stashed Commits".

Comment: Looks like there was a contest: "How to best hide a standard feature"! And wehn you try to unstash something you get a nice "conflict" dialog which makes it impossible to unstash it. Furthermore in the stash view you can compare files but not export any patch. Which idiot has designed this UI - GIT integration in Eclipse is next to useless!

Comment: I did not have much of an issue with this, clicked on checkout, files appeared in "Staged Changes" and I pulled them back up to the unstaged changes. All restored. Then deleted the stash commit.